# Web application + SQL server triggers / thresholds

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, triggers

We have a web application that is hosted in IIS. In our database that serves the application we have all kinds of different data values. We are trying to figure out a way to have an email sent to a client if a certain data value exists or exceeds a threshold value.

Generic Example:
Say we have a table that lists widgets and their 'in inventory' quantity. Every time someone sells a widget, this quantity value would be depleted. We want to send an email to the manager when the widget quantity gets below 5 and tell him to reorder more widgets.

We don't want to have sql triggers that check the quantity any time a 'depletion' transaction takes place. Instead, we want some type of background monitoring process that checks the level of the widgets on a timed basis. How can we accomplish this? Windows Service / WinForm application? Something built into IIS that will run ASP.net C# code?

Comment: Would this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx  <-- listens for changes via SqlDependency object. Wrap this bad boy up in a SignalR enabled web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polling based monitoring should be your last resort. It uses too many resources for a simple task and most of the time it will only see that it's not the case to do anything. And it doesn't even scale when your data grows.

Instead, you should focus on the code that changes those values and act then, on in spot. And the check will also be lighter: only one item being checked not all, and only once, not every x seconds/minutes/hours/...

Apart from the architectural considerations, to answer your question, just as Jonathan said: anything that can read a database and send emails will do, but I'd consider a Windows Service for this job because that's what they were made for: background jobs running all the time, unrelated to the host users. You also get some extra benefits like automatic startup and recovery options.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that can read the database and send an email could accomplish this - console app, winforms app, web app -- it doesn't really matter.

It may be more efficient to monitor when the values are changed (what changes them? A web application?) and have *that* application also send notifications